# find pdf text position

Tags: pdf, text, position

I'm struggling with the calculation of pdf text position. I've read through internet, but without success.
I've read the pdf reference, but it's uhmmmm.
Now, I write a piece of pdf and I'll tell you my thinking about it...

```
/TT3 1 Tf
11.9951 0 0 12 71.94 420.9803 Tm     //scale x=11.9951  scaley=12   x position=71.94 y position=420.9803
<0003>Tj
/TT2 1 Tf
1.6657 -1.22 TD   //x position=71.94+1.6657 y position=420.9803-1.22
-.0016 Tc
(2\))Tj   //x position=71.94+1.6657-0.0016 y position=420.9803-1.22
/TT6 1 Tf
.8203 0 TD   //x position=71.94+1.6657-0.0016+0.8203
0 Tc
( )Tj
/TT3 1 Tf
10.016 0 0 10.02 71.94 237.6803 Tm  //x position=71.94 y position=237.6803
<0003>Tj
/TT2 1 Tf
```

I'm sure that something is wrong, because with this method the sequence is not rebuilt correctly.
Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you shouldn't try to keep track of multiple scalars separately but instead of the whole current text matrix and text line matrix.

Then you ripped those instructions from the context. So we have to assume no relevant instructions preceded them.

Thus, we start with text matrix and text line matrix equal to the identity matrix.

```
/TT3 1 Tf
11.9951 0 0 12 71.94 420.9803 Tm
```

This sets both the text matrix and the text line matrix to

```
11.9951  0       0
 0      12       0
71.94  420.9803  1
```

Then

```
<0003>Tj
```

advances the text matrix by the width of this string. As I don't know the metrics of **TT3**, I cannot tell the resulting text matrix.

```
/TT2 1 Tf
1.6657 -1.22 TD
```

This multiplies

```
1       0    0
0       1    0
1.6657 -1.22 1
```

to the text line matrix from the left, resulting in the new text line matrix (slightly rounded)

```
11.9951    0       0
 0        12       0
91.92    406.3403  1
```

Then the text matrix is set to this value, too.

```
(2\))Tj
```

This advances the text matrix by the width of this string. As I don't know the metrics of **TT2**, I cannot tell the resulting text matrix. I don't even know whether this string in **TT2** represents one or two glyphs. Thus, I cannot tell how often the character spacing is applied.

```
/TT6 1 Tf
.8203 0 TD
```

This multiplies

```
1       0    0
0       1    0
0.8203  0    1
```

to the text line matrix from the left, resulting in the new text line matrix (slightly rounded)

```
 11.9951    0       0
  0        12       0
101.76    406.3403  1
```

Now

```
0 Tc
( )Tj
```

This advances the text matrix by the width of this string. As I don't know the metrics of **TT6**, I cannot tell the resulting text matrix.

```
/TT3 1 Tf
10.016 0 0 10.02 71.94 237.6803 Tm
```

This sets both the text matrix and the text line matrix to

```
10.016    0        0
0        10.02     0
71.94   237.6803   1
```

Comment: In this case, TT6 contains only 0x20, the space, so I have only this width.
So, to obtain the new matrix, I have only to multiply
    1            0                  0
    0            1                  0
    (0.278+Tc)   0            1
for Tm?.

Comment: That looks reasonable.

Comment: Another question about this, I have a font, TT2, in which width is an array, and it is written First char=41 and Last char=130, in the pdf I have no Cmap for this so I don't know what is the char number 41. I have supposed that 41 stands for ascii 41, but position does not correspond. Do you know how to find this?Thank you.

Comment: From the string object in the content stream you read the bytes. Use these byte values as index. No transformation required.

Comment: @doxdici Did my answer help you? Are there still open questions? If it has and there aren't, you may consider [marking my answer as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) (by clicking the tick at its upper left)

Comment: I haven't understand yet, sorry, because for the font TT2, in my PDF is <</BaseFont/EFAAOB+Calibri-Bold/Encoding/WinAnsiEncoding/FirstChar 41/FontDescriptor 92 0 R/LastChar 120/Subtype
/TrueType/Type/Font/Widths[312 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 507 507 507 507 507 507 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 606 0 529 630
488 459 0 631 267 0 0 423 0 659 676 0 0 563 473 495 0 591 0 0 520 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 494 0 418 537 503 316
474 537 246 0 480 246 813 537 538 537 0 355 399 347 537 473 745 459]>>     but I don't understand which is the char 41 (width 312) and which the char 120 (width 459), and all the intermediate chars

Comment: @doxdici What do you mean by *"which is the char 41"*? When you parse the bytes of a content stream and (while **TT2** is the current font) come upon a string argument of a text showing operator, and in that string argument there is a byte 41 =  0x29, then the glyph drawn for that byte has a width 312 thousands of a text space unit, i.e. before being scaled by font size and transformations. Due to the **Encoding** value **WinAnsiEncoding** you know that the glyph in question should be a "1" but that is not of interest at all here.

Comment: Due to the Encoding value WinAnsiEncoding you know that the glyph in question should be a "1" but that is not of interest at all here. How do you know if byte is corresponding to the glyph 1?In TT2, char are written al letters, so, is             
 /TT2 1 Tf
.225 0 TD
.0006 Tc
[(Se)4(t)12.3(t)2.3(ing)]TJ
/TT1 1 Tf
2.91 0 TD
0 Tc
<0003>Tj              //TT2 is in letters, TT1 in bytes, but TT1 has a cmap, TT2 no

Comment: *"How do you know if byte is corresponding to the glyph 1?"* - see above, due to the **Encoding** value **WinAnsiEncoding**. In that encoding the "1" has the value 41.

Comment: Furthermore, I don't know details of your font **TT1** because you haven't shown its font dictionary. **TT2** on the other hand with **Subtype** value **TrueType** is a *Simple Font*, and Simple Fonts have single-byte encodings. And the encoding is even explicitly mentioned, **WinAnsiEncoding**.

Comment: My problem is to calculate glyph width for TT2, to correctly position the text. Do "Widths[312…459] , Firstchar 41/LastChar 120" what glyphs correspond to??

Comment: Ok, now I unserstand, first char is the ascii code of the first glyph of the list, and the subsequents are the Others in ascii order.

Comment: @doxdici I wouldn't call it ascii codes (**WinAnsiEncoding** has ASCII as a subset, so it *looks* like ascii codes here, but there are other encodings, too, which are not derived from ASCII). It's simply the ascending sequence of integers from **FirstChar** to **LastChar**, i.e. 41, 42, 43, 44, ..., 118, 119, 120 in your **TT1**.